# Why is a random zero appearing every time I run this macro?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am using a command button to run the macro below, but a zero keeps on appearing on the sheet on a random cell everytime I run I run the macro. The macro being used is from a recorded macro just noting that in case maybe that's why. The recorded macro all it is it's taking references from another sheet and autofiling in another.

```
Sub Refresh()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='raw data'!R[-5]C"
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A7:A500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would put a 0 in a random cell. The result of the formula is posted to the cell which is active at the time of you pressing the button. If the formula is pointing to an empty cell it will produce a `0` - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion  and I also just realized that. Is there a way to not add that zero?

Comment: Can you change your formula?`=IF('raw data'!A2="","",'raw data'!A2)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is where your `activecell` is located when you run the code.

This will solve that problem.

```
Range("A7:A500") = "='raw data'!R[-5]C"
```

Just to add an additional option:

```
Sub Values()
Range("A7:A500").Value = Sheets("raw data").Range("A2:A500").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, that would insert a relative formula in each cell. I think the OP wants the result of a specific cell from the raw data sheet copied into each cell instead.

Comment: Were you able to see my comment earlier?

Comment: @MacroMan, the formula is relative

Comment: Yes but in the original code, the value of A7 is copied to the range, not the formula.